# Approximation of exp$(-a/x)$ near $x=0$

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function, laurent-series

The function

\begin{equation}
f(x) = e^{-a/x}
\end{equation}

has a finite value at zero. If I were to Taylor expand $e^{-az}$ and substitute $z = x^{-1}$ I will have a series expansion but it wouldn't be useful since all the terms go as powers of $x^{-1}$. I'm wondering, since this function is finite and analytic near the origin, is there a series representation for this function near $x=0^+$?

For reference, this is what the function looks like for $a=1$:

[image]

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm interested in a series representation of the Boltzmann factor 
$$e^{-H/kT}$$
at low, but finite, temperatures. So I'm interested in the case that $a$ and $x$ are both real and positive.

Comment: There is nothing analytic about this function at $x=0$.

Comment: It might help to look at it for negative $x$ as well as positive.

Comment: Yes, even if you assume $a>0$, you only get a finite limit as $x\to 0^+$, not as $x\to 0^-$.

Comment: Personally, I find $0$ to be a suitable approximation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for $a>0$, for small and positive $x$. I edited the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a not-half-bad approximation that's relatively simple:
$$e^{-a/x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\approx f_k(x),\quad\text{large enough }k$$
where
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x\le\frac an\\\left(1-\frac a{nx}\right)^n,&x>\frac an\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can approximate

$$e^{-1/x}$$

for sufficiently small positive $x$ then you'll have solved your problem.

Define

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\left(1-\frac1{nx}\right)^n,&x>\frac1n\\0,&0\le x\le\frac1n\end{cases}$$

$$g_n(x)=\left(1+\frac1{nx}\right)^{-n}$$

Then,

$$f_n(x)\le e^{-1/x}\le g_n(x),\quad0\le x$$

This approach is effective because

$$1-\frac1{nx}$$

can easily be approximated for small positive $x$ for sufficiently large $n$. An even better approximation would be

$$e^{-1/x}\approx\frac{f_n(x)+g_n(x)}2$$

For example, if you want an error of $E<0.01$, then setting $n=5$ is enough:

$$\left|e^{-1/x}-\frac{f_5(x)+g_5(x)}2\right|<0.01$$